# Excel countifs ignore one specific column

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

=if(COUNTIFS('Finishing Results'!G5:N5,'Finishing Results'!P5:AC5,"1")=0,COUNTIFS('Finishing Results'!G5:N5,'Finishing Results'!P5:AC5,"1"))

Trying to exclude ('Finishing Results'!O5:O34)on both ends of the formula.

Comment: please edit your question and explain what you would like to achieve. The Countifs function syntax does not work like that and it's difficult to understand what you want to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore one column/row/area in a countifs, just split and combine/add two separate countifs e.g. to skip col D

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:C1, 1) + COUNTIFS(E1:F1, 1)
```

Comment: What if I am trying to find the min of a range excluding that column?

Ex:-Min('Race Points Results'!G5:AC5)

Comment: MIN, MAX, SUM, AVERAGE etc. all accepts multiple arguments, so you can do (using my example ranges) `=MIN(A1:C1, E1:F1)`. If some formula does not allow multiple arguments, you can try using multiple area references i.e. define a reference in brackets e.g. (A1:C1, E1:F1). Excel calls each of those areas. The AREAS functions will count the number of areas in a reference. Using the INDEX function, you can index into different areas e.g. `=INDEX((A1:C1, E1:F1),1,1,2)` will return the first row and column in area 2 (value in E1). Unfortunately COUNTIF(S) does not support mulitple area references.